# How to develop a module in dolibarr 13.0.1

Tags: dolibarr

I'm a Student and I'm doing my project of my final year to graduate.  They ask me to develop a module of currency conversion in dolibarr 13.0.1 on ubuntu LST 20.04 but I didn't find any documentation helps me to know how to do that.  Can anyone help me please?!

Answer (score 1):

If you are still struggling with this, there is a built-in module builder in Dolibarr.

Go to Home > Setup > Modules/Applications and scroll to section
Multi-modules tools. There you have a module named "MODULE AND APPLICATION BUILDER".

After activation, you will see a spider icon at the top right of the screen. Clicking on it will take you to the page where you can create a new module, and add hooks, triggers etc. to it.

More information can be found on [Dolibarr developer documentation](https://wiki.dolibarr.org/index.php?title=Developer_documentation)